# Solving diophantine equation with coefficients

Tags: diophantine-equations

We know this equation : $$ x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_n = c$$ and also the number of solutions is obvious . But how we can understand number of solutions in this equation :
$$ a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 + \dots + a_nx_n = k$$

Please Help!

Comment: See the answers [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/649329/linear-diophantine-equation-count-number-of-solutions-that-satisfies-a-certain).

Comment: @Dietrich Burde Thank you , But it seems in this page hasn't any certain and complete answer for this question